# You don't have the permissions to save the file!

Tags: permissions, files

i am using bootable Ubuntu in my ACER [win10] and my issue is, i want to edit some file in efi/efivars, and i use GHEX tool to edit the file but when i want to save the file, it will pop.up "You don't have the permissions to save the file!".
anyone can suggest or help me?

[image]

Comment: "i want to edit some file in efi/efivars"  You can not edit files that are on a read only file system. So in case you still read this: provide details on the partitions (more /etc/fstab or from fdisk -l).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the command:
lsattr
.If the file has the attribute i you have to use:
chattr -i yourfile
.That solves the problem and will let you edit it.

Comment: I don't think I ever saw files protected with the "-i" on a system unless it was manually set by a user afterwards. That he is editing on a read only filesystem might be the more obvious reason.

Comment: I had the same problem and I solved it like that